# Why does SHA-256 message digest give different result in j2objc?

Tags: j2objc

I'm getting a different result when running my code in Java and j2obc.  My java code looks like this:

```
import java.security.DigestException;
import java.security.MessageDigest;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import java.util.Base64;

public class TestScrypt {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, DigestException {
        MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256");
        md.update(new byte[64]);
        byte[] tmp = md.digest();
        md.digest(tmp, 0, tmp.length);
        System.out.println("Result:" + Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(tmp));
    }
}
```

When I run this on my 64-bit Mac with Java 1.8.0_152 I get this output:
`Result:47DEQpj8HBSa+/TImW+5JCeuQeRkm5NMpJWZG3hSuFU=`

But when I compile using j2objc (and link using the  -ObjC -ljre_emul flags) I get this output:
`Result:9aX9QtFqIDAnmO9u0wmXm0MAPSMg2fDo6pgxqSdZ+0s=`

Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You found a bug in j2objc's support for `md.digest(tmp, 0, tmp.length)`: it returns an updated hash as `md.digest(tmp)`, but should instead return an non-updated digest. I filed [issue #929](https://github.com/google/j2objc/issues/929), which you can subscribe to to be notified when it's fixed.

Comment: Thanks! By the way your fast response to this and other stack overflow j2objc questions gives me confidence I can use j2objc in production

Comment: If you want even faster bug turnaround, we happily accept patches! ;-)